# Azure Databricks connectivity from Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-databricks

We are having following setup :-

1. Azure Linux VM in subnet1 inside VNET01
2. Azure databricks hosted using custom connected VNET inside VNET01.

While making a connection from Azure VM with ADB we are facing following issue :-

export DATABRICKS_TOKEN=sdgsdgsyd2382732

**curl -X GET --header "Authorization: Bearer $DATABRICKS_TOKEN" https://adb-xyz.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/clusters/list -vvv**

- About to connect() to adb-xyz.azuredatabricks.net port 443 (#0)
- Trying 40.74.30.80...
- Connected to adb-xyz.azuredatabricks.net (30.85.20.80) port 443 (#0)
- Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
- CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
- NSS error -5938 (PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR)
- Encountered end of

It is able to connect to ADB host however fails afterward, we suspect its related to certificates, if it is how can this be resolved, if not, can someone please explain how to handle this issue and make a connection?

Comment: check with admins, maybe you have IP Access List enabled on workspace.

Comment: You should just need to use Vnet Injection for the databricks account so you can then deploy the VM and the databricks into the same Virtual Network : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT, both ADB and Azure VM are in same virtual network.

Comment: @AlexOtt, sure, i am not sure, if Access list is enabled, one recommendation was to go via NSP (Network secure Perimeter), i am currently looking into it.